# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object how to resolve this issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting this error

> Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in /var/www/html/ocrs/public/index.php on line 10

my code is given below

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        if($source->Query("SELECT * FROM instructor Where name LIKE  ? ", ["%".$search."%"])){        
            if($source->CountRows() > 0){
                $row = $source->fetchAll();
                $name =  $row->name;
                echo $name;
                print_r($row);
                echo"</br>";
                var_dump($row);
            }else{
                echo "No user found";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Query not working";
        }
    }
```

Result of `print_r()` and `var_dump()`

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [name] => test1 [email] => test1@test.com [password] => $2b$10$CHb69p4oJ4.b4oIobIqFjuIJB4KAL66qn9z7y9NGurXKWd8/nakei ) )
>
> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(5) "test1" ["email"]=> string(14) "test1@test.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2b$10$CHb69p4oJ4.b4oIobIqFjuIJB4KAL66qn9z7y9NGurXKWd8/nakei" } }

It is clearly shown in `print_r` and `var_dump` that it is an object not an array then why it is not working?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by using

```
foreach($source->fetchAll() as $row){
 echo $row->name;
}
```

Comment: Great job. This is also another tricky technique